# Exception handling with messaging

Tags: .net, exception, real-time, esper

I have a system  that receives MSMQ messages and performs (close to)  real-time analysis using [NEsper](http://esper.codehaus.org/). It is possible that some messages come late and perhaps in different order. This situation shall be flagged up and reported. Write not this is how it is working (meta code):

```
//shows how many messages came in wrong order
private int error;

//processing function
void MessageReceived(Message m)
{
    //the message is from the `past`
    //if compared to the engine time
    if(m.Occured < currentEngineTime)
    {
        error++; // I think there is a beter way to do this
    }

    // update engine time if required
    //engine time is manually adjusted with
    //each newest message

    //perform analysis of the message    
    //pass message to the engine processing pipeline
}
```

How do I better handle the situation where a message arrives "from the past", I cannot throw an exception as I still need the message to be processed, but I want the user to know more details about the message rather just saying that there was *N* incorrectly received messages. I was thinking to do something like AggregateException, but not sure how that works. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your user supposed to do with this information?  Is there actually anything she can do to prevent this from happening?  Or is it actually a bug you don't know how to fix?  Consider raising an event that the UI can do something with or log it somewhere.

Comment: @Hans At this stage the user is supposed to be aware of the event and get details of which message came with a delay. Seems like the idea of firing an event is what I really  need, could you post this as an answer?